# getting an error when calling an on resume activity in fragment call-android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to call on resume activity in my fragment class but I am getting the following error

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.start_gps);
        task.update();
    }
```

this is error

```
01-27 00:53:52.138: E/AndroidRuntime(29010): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 00:53:52.138: E/AndroidRuntime(29010): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 00:53:52.138: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at com.lifesymb.gps.StartActivity.onResume(StartActivity.java:137)
01-27 00:53:52.138: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1521)
01-27 00:53:52.138: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:963)
01-27 00:53:52.138: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-27 00:53:52.138: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-27 00:53:52.138: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
01-27 00:53:52.138: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
01-27 00:53:52.138: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-27 00:53:52.138: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-27 00:53:52.138: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
01-27 00:53:52.138: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
01-27 00:53:52.138: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 00:53:52.138: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 00:53:52.138: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
01-27 00:53:52.138: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
01-27 00:53:52.138: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely to be with the `task` variable, you have probably not re/initialized it. Set content view should be done in onCreate, you don't need to do it on resume